# Django unique combination is duplicate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web, django-models

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'Restauarant' for key 'restaurants_restaurant_name_address_id_e074fa2e_uniq'")
```

Above is the error. As shown in the model for a restaurant I have defined that the address and name should be unique together. Though when I create a restaurant, if the combination of name and address are unique but either of them are the same as another restaurant object then this fails. E.G. "Restaurant" at "10 Something Street" would fail if there were an existing object like "Restaurant" at "35 Something Else Street." Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    route = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=116)  # 2* 58 (longest place name)
    administrative_area_level_1 = models.CharField(max_length=116, default=None)  
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    country = CountryField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    menu = models.ManyToManyField(Menu)
    favourites = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        # ensures unique combination, prevents duplicate 'restaurants'
        unique_together = ((
            'name',
            'street_number',
            'route',
            'locality',
            'administrative_area_level_1',
            'postal_code',
            'country'
        ))
```

Comment: Your error message contains `address` but not your code, so I suspect you made a different constraint previously and haven't migrated correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I found where I made that mistake though I can't fix it as it throws an error migrating that change: ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for restaurants_restaurant(name, address_id)

Comment: Please note that python code will not get the correct format in a code snippet. Please use code sample instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code that might be causing the error.

`unique_together` should be a tuple of tuples, but you've missed a comma after the inner tuple the parenthesis .

This might help:

```
unique_together = ((
    'name',
    'street_number',
    'route',
    'locality',
    'administrative_area_level_1',
    'postal_code',
    'country'
), )
```

Now you might not get that error when you re-run migrations.

Also just quickly - it might be more meaningful to set uniqueness on `slug` rather than `name`, assuming slug is derived from name. You wouldn't want something to slip past the unique constraint due to a change in case.